# Join tables with additional conditions

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm a little bit out of ideas. I have a table in which I have following datas:

```
ID  | timedate     | value | ...
 1  | 04-16-2017   | 3     | ...
 1  | 04-20-2017   | 4     | ...
 1  | 04-24-2017   | 10    |...[approx 100k different IDs)
```

Now, a user search for (e.g) ID = 1. In my View I want to show the different cols and the difference in Value. But the difference should only be from last timedate to second last timedate, like this:

```
ID  |  timedate   | value   | dif.Value
1   | 04-24-2017  |   10    |  6  [10-4]
```

My actual mySQL-Query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
 tab.Id AS `tab__Id`, 
 tab.timedate AS `tab__timedate`, 
 tab.value AS `tab__value`, 
 tab.value - t2.value AS `difValue`, 
FROM 
 tab tab
INNER JOIN tab3 t3 ON t3.Id = tab.Id 
INNER JOIN tab t2 ON t2.Id = tab.Id 
  WHERE 
  (t3.Id like '1' 
   AND tab.timedate IN (
   SELECT 
    max(tab.timedate) 
   FROM 
    tab
  GROUP BY 
    tab.Id
   )
  ) 
GROUP BY 
 tab.Id
LIMIT 
10 OFFSET 0
```

Coming from cakePHP3 =

```
$search= $tab->find('all')
             ->select(['Id', 'tab.timedate ', 'tab.value','difValue' => 
               'tab.value - t2.value'])
             ->andWhere(['t3.Id LIKE' => $id])
             ->where(['tab.timedate IN (SELECT max(tab.timedate) FROM tab 
               GROUP BY tab.Id)'])
             ->distinct(['tab.Id'])
                ->join([
                    't3' => [
                        'table' => 'tab3',
                        'conditions' => 't3.Id= tab.Id ',
                    ],
                    't2' => [
                        'table' => 'tab',
                        'conditions' => ' t2.Id= tab.Id
                    ]
                ]);
```

How can I set the Join (t2) that he take the second last date for t2.value? I tried to add this to my condition t2, but it takes the first timedate

```
 ...AND tab.timedate > t2.timedate - INTERVAL 1 DAY'
```

Maybe there is another way to solve this. I just want to calc the diff. of last timedate: value and second last timedate: value **(Last Value - second last Value => "difValue")**

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of that query to this problem !?!?

Comment: the problem is that my join "t2" should only select the second last timedate. Maybe there is a another way to solve this. (The query with the join is my idea to solve this). I just want to calc the diff. of the last timedate: value and the second last timedate: value

Answer (score 0):

I've added, not subtracted, for clarity - and just to be different. Note that the reference to 'current' in the outer query is really just a reference to whatever happens to be the primary key.

```
SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+

SELECT total 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT @i:=@i+i total
            , @i:=i current 
         FROM ints
            , (SELECT @i:=0) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY i DESC 
        LIMIT 2
     ) x 
 ORDER 
    BY current 
 LIMIT 1;
+-------+
| total |
+-------+
|    17 |
+-------+
```

Comment: i've understand it, but how can I implement this into my cakePHP3 query?

Comment: I guess you don't understand it then ;-)

Comment: I see only possible way to use this query as a raw statement ($res = $con -> execute("") )  But with cakePHP Query Builder i don't know a way!

Comment: I found a better solution than this! Just select the value > order it by timestamp > Set Limit with offset.